# How to show the associative properties in $\pi_1(X,x_0)?$

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

$\pi_1(X,x_0)$ is  a group with respect to the product $[f][g]=[f.g]$

satisfy three properties

$1. $Associative

$2.$ Identity

$3.$Inverse

**My question** : How to show the associative properties in $\pi_1(X,x_0)?$

My attempt : I was reading the Allen Hatcher book but im not understand fully

In Allen book it is written that  given $3$ path  $f,g,h$ with $f(1)=g(0)$ and $g(1)=h(0)$
implies $(f.g).h=f(g.h)$

Actually  i don't understand the Allen book  because he doesn't explain in detail that why $(f.g).h=f(g.h)?$

Comment: It's not true that $(f.g).h=f.(g.h)$ and I'm pretty sure Hatcher doesn't claim that. What is true, is that $(f.g).h$ and $f.(g.h)$ are *homotopic* as paths (maps $I\to X$) relative their endpoints.

Comment: That is, you have only $([f][g])[h] = [f] ([g][h])$.

Comment: @Christoph u r correct  im sorry for that that my misread

Comment: **A bad formula(draw in square, two inclined lines):** $$(s,t)\longmapsto \begin{cases} f\left(\frac{4s}{1+t}\right)&\text{ if }0\leq s\leq\frac{t+1}{4},\\ g(4s-1-t) &\text{ if }\frac{t+1}{4}\leq s\leq \frac{t+2}{4},\\ h\left(\frac{4s-2-t}{2-t}\right)&\text{ if }\frac{t+2}{4}\leq s\leq 1.\end{cases}$$ Use this to show $(f*g)*h\simeq_{\text{ rel }x_0}f*(g*h)$.

Comment: @Mathlover here $t$ denote time  Am i right ?

Comment: Yeah. $t$ is used for time.